# Por que suprimir o zero antes do ponto em decimais, como em 0.5 == .5?

Tags: javascript, sintaxe, decimal

Algumas vezes encaro um código em que o programador escreveu um decimal sem o zero, como `0.5` sendo `.5`, por exemplo:

```js
var decimal1 = 0.5;
var decimal2 = .5;

console.log(decimal1 == decimal2);
console.log(decimal1, decimal2);
```

**No meu ponto de vista**, escrever um decimal como `.5` deixa a leitura prejudicada, então sempre prefiro utilizá-lo com o zero: `0.5`.

O que realmente ocorre quando determinamos um decimal sem o zero antes do ponto? Porque conseguimos definir uma variável decimal desse jeito? Há diferenças entre as duas maneiras? Existe algum aumento na performance?

Comment: Alguém pode dizer o porquê do `-1`?

Comment: Há uma técnica de, quanto menos letras numa página, menos peso. Mas não sei se escrever assim chega vale a pena. Observe o que os otimizadores/redutores de javascript fazem com a página, alguns chegam "comer" parte de código que eu teria vergonha de escrever.

Comment: Não ter o "0" antes não afeta negativamente a legibilidade (no caso geral). É uma convenção amplamente aceita. Por ou não acaba por se tornar apenas uma questão estilística e cultural.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, sim. Explicitei que é no *meu ponto de vista*, será por isso os votos negativos? Mas por que existe essa questão estilística e por que a linguagem permite? O `.x` existe por algum motivo?

Comment: Pode testar até em uma calculadora caseira, se digitar .5, ela vai entender que é 0.5.
Acho que é só por convenção mesmo, na faculdade, tinha uma matéria de cálculo numérico, onde tinha um tópico que ensinava as melhores práticas de arredondamento, onde usávamos números bem capciosos, tipo 0.0089240544....
Ai na hora de escrevermos na calculadora, o professor mesmo recomendava essa forma .0089240544 porque querendo ou não, acaba ficando mais fácil pra gente escrever, e na hora de ler no display da calculadora, parece piada, mas 1 caractere a menos acabava facilitando, e muito!

Comment: @MarceloBoni, legal. Já notei que em outras linguagens isso ocorre também. A resposta pra isso fica além da programação, então? Fiquei ainda mais curioso... Eu tinha um professor que dizia o contrário, embora não fossemos fazer uma conta em uma calculadora, dizia para manter o zero para não nos perdermos nas contas.

Comment: Acho que entra no mesmo caso de números definidos como `0x, 0b e 0o` [vide](https://jsfiddle.net/rjzk6n4f/). O interpretador do javascript utiliza alguma regex pra detectar o que vem após o `0x`, `0b`, `0o` e `.` para fazer o calculo de conversão... note que se você escrever apenas `.` sem nenhum número após, o console emite um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: @bio é padrão que o reconhecimento de números de ponto flutuante seja fornecido através de algo próximo da expressão `([1-9][0-9]*|0?)(\.[0-9]*)?`

Comment: O que me preocupa é isso funcionar: `console.log(parseFloat(".2fhh.95fgh/4")); // 0.2` por exemplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> O que realmente ocorre quando determinamos um decimal sem o zero antes do ponto?

Nada, essa é uma questão de sintaxe, não muda a execução, o significado, nada, só tem um caractere a menos.

O número é o mesmo, isso é só uma representação dele na tela neste contexto. Note que o escrito na tela também é só uma representação textual. Convencionou-se sempre colocar o 0 antes do ponto, o que parece um pouco incoerente.

JS não é conhecida por ter uma forte exigência de sintaxe estrita.

> Por que conseguimos definir uma variável decimal desse jeito?

A resposta simples e óbvia é que a linguagem definiu assim. Como não há ambiguidade acharam que não era necessário obrigar algo só pela legibilidade.

Uma hipótese é manter a linguagem menos verbosa, ainda que isso seria questionável. Até falaram sobre ficar um arquivo menor, mas isso ocorre tão poucas vezes que duvido que seria uma boa motivação. Se fosse o caso a linguagem teria outras coisas que permitem o texto menor de forma mais intensa e com menos problemas de legibilidade.

A matemática meio que define assim, zeros no inteiro à esquerda do número não possuem significado, e por isso pode ser omitido. Assim como os zeros à direita na parte decimal.

> Há diferenças entre as duas maneiras?

Zero.

> Existe algum aumento na performance?

Zero.

Faça como achar melhor, até porque tem pouca relevância.

Comment: Quando criei essa questão imaginei algo diferente. Depois dos comentários percebi que não fazia muito sentido. Pensei que o `.5` existia por algum motivo, mas graças a vocês sei que é uma questão de sintaxe e é comum no meio matemático. Obrigado pela resposta.